# How to check if all optional members of a class have been set?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to check if all optional properties of my class have been set.

I can write a function checking each property, but I was wondering if there is a quicker method to iterate among properties, or just a feature to check if all class members have been initialised.

Comment: When do you want to check if they are all set?

Comment: First of all, you need to get a list of those properties. Swift has no reflection so you cannot do that without naming the properties explicitly.

Comment: Could you tell us why you even need this? There are probably better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* do that.

The problem is even getting the list of all properties because Swift has no reflection.

However, if you can make your objects inherit from `NSObject`, then you can use Obj-C runtime to do that (with some limitations though).

Answer (score 0):

you can define a stored property

```
var allPropertiesAreInitialised: Bool{
      get {
          return val1 =! nil && val2 =! nil //etc ...
      }
}
```

Comment: not good, this solution is not scalable.

Comment: Perfectly fine, considering that checking all properties are non-nil without actually knowing all the properties is rather pointless. You are assuming that a class or struct could never acquire a truly nullable property.

Answer (score -1):

Properties of optional type are automatically initialized with a value of nil, indicating that the property is deliberately intended to have “no value yet” during initialization. So just check if optional property is nil to know if it is set.

Comment: I believe the author knows how optionals work. Rather he is asking how he can check all the optionals in a class easily at once, even if there are a great many of them.

Comment: yes just check for nil one by one, please see above